# Добавить класс к блоку и сохранить в localstorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Задача - добавить и удалить класс style_block при нажатии на кнопку change_list, и при обновлении страницы не сбрасывать его. проблема с localstorage, вот html и js с сайта:

```
<a href="#" class="change_list">change</a>
    <div class="content_box">
       ...
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".change_list").click(function(){
                $(".content_box").toggleClass("style_block");
                    localStorage.setItem('content_box_class', 'style_block');
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Как правильно получить сохранённое значение через localStorage.getItem и вывести его?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      if (localStorage.getItem('content_box') == 'style_block') {
        $('.content_box').addClass('style_block');
      }
});

$(".change_list").click(function() {
     $('.content_box').toggleClass('style_block');
      if (localStorage.getItem('content_box') == 'style_block') {
        localStorage.removeItem("content_box", "style_block");
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("content_box", "style_block");
      }

}); 
</script>
```